# phone7, silverlight, move copy or rename files?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any way in Phone7 to rename a file? I don't see anything in IsolatedStorageFile that exposes this functionality but perhaps I'm missing something? It seems like the best way to rename a file is to read its contents and write them to another file and then delete the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.movefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) was only added to Silverlight in version 4. So, as WP7 is based on Silverlight 3 you'll need to create your own move/rename function.